# MVC Controller looks for an aspx page by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a solution with one web application which contains Models and Views and the Controllers in a separate class library. I have Razor views in my views folder. When I type in the url (e.g. Home/Index) the constructor correctly finds the correct view index.cshtml, however If If don't enter the actions name, I get an error stating that the Resource can't be found and the requested url is  /Home/index.aspx.

How can I make the constructor look for razor views by default. My route config is just the standard default one.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" },
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
```

except I have a reference to the Controllers namespace.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a default value for the controller, in your default route.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" },
                defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have added the default for controller="Home", but still get the same error.